# How can I display all of the information from a single column from MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

I am programming a discord bot and am fairly new with MySQL. I've tried to do this myself, but maybe I'm missing something.

I want to display all of the information from a specific column for all rows in a table. It'll do that, however, my method has so far proven to send three separate discord messages, and I would like it only to send one.

I know that `i++` will increment, but I didn't think it'd increment into three messages. Not too sure what to do about this, as I'm not an expert.

Many thanks in advance!!

```
const [check1, check1d, check1e] = await pool.query("SELECT `TeamName` FROM `performancetracker`.`queue`");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < check1.length; [i++]) {
  const result = (`${check1 [i].TeamName}`)

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Test Name")
    .setDescription(`Test Description`)
    .addField('Team Name:', `${result}`, true)
    .setTimestamp()

  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: Are there three rows in your database? Don't send the message inside your `for` loop but concat the message and send only one message _after_ the `for` loop

Comment: You have the code that sends a single message _inside_ your loop, so of course that results in three messages getting sent then, if your loop iterates three times. _"and I would like it only to send one"_ - then concatenate your data into a variable inside your loop, and send a message with that variable's content _after_ the loop.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code? Also, are you really facing any problem related to Discord?

Comment: Nico Haase > Sorry that I flagged it as so, I thought maybe some from the PHP/Discord community might have an answer on this. The php is in the query, it's just changed to allow constant within the query. This lets me insert things defined by other pieces in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `message.channel.send()`on every loop, thus the message will be sent again. You need to use it after the loop is done.

You also need to define the embed before the loop and only use `.addField()` inside of it.

Like this:

```
var i;

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Test Name")
  .setDescription(`Test Description`)
  .setTimestamp()

for (i = 0; i < check1.length; [i++]) {
  const result = (`${check1 [i].TeamName}`)
  embed.addField('Team Name:', `${result}`, true)
}

message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Comment: I didn't think about it being inside the loop, and I really should have though of that. Also, thank you for pointing out that I'd need to add a field for each increment. This helps a ton! Much appreciation your way.